# confused in copy constructor and objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I saw the others question on Stack Overflow but they only answered a part of it.
suppose we have a class-

```
class student
{
public:    
    string name;    
    student(string a)
    {
        name = a;
        cout << "parmeteised const." << endl;
    }

    student(student &a)
    {
        name = a.name;
        cout << "Copy const." << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student a("Vyom");
    student c(a);
    if (a == c)
    {
        cout << "same";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile and gives an error-

```
no operator "==" matches these operands -- operand types are: student == student
```

Now I know that this is wrong and I would have to overload the operator to do so.
**My Doubts:**

1. We have argument `&a` in the copy constructor but we input only `a` while making an object `c`.
2. If point 1 is true and valid then it probably means `a` stands for the memory location of the object.
3. if point 2 is true and valid then why can't I compare memory locations of `a` and `c` 
   **(I know memory locations will be in hexadecimal but there must be a way to convert them into int and then compare).**
   I am beginner, please help me clarify my doubts.

Comment: You are correct that there is no copy of object a from the main frame into the contructor frame, since you're using a reference. But that doesn't mean "a stands for the memory location of the object". That's because when C++ takes a parameter by reference, under the hood, it looks up the memory address of that object, but you as the programmer don't need to pass that pointer at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. We have argument &a in the copy constructor but we input only a while making an object c.

In the function `student(student &a)` variable 'a' is reference on a student. It is not a pointer (`student* a`).

You will have to implement the comparison operator `==` if you want to compare two `student` objects:
[operator_comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

Comment: I was confused about it thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that `student &a` is a reference. `&a` on it's own could very well mean the the address of a variable `a`.

Comment: @churill : You are right, I changed my answer a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: @churill so now it means that both `a` and `c` point to the same memory location as they have same address as I have passed by reference. So does this means they are the same objects?

Comment: @VyomYadav Maybe worth to explain that a and c are clones at different memory locations and it remains up to the coder to determine when clones are identical:  e.g. is it sufficient that they have the same name, or must all the other member variables (if there were others) also match? must the strings be exactly the same or can their case vary without affecting identity? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to overload (implement) `==` operator for the class. Below is a sample `==` operator implementation for your class -

```
bool operator==(const student& a) const {
    if (a.name == this->name) return true;
    
    return false;
  }
```

Now your code should look like below -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
public:    
   string name;    
   student(string a)
   {
    name = a;
    cout << "parmeteised const." << endl;
}

student(student &a)
{
    name = a.name;
    cout << "Copy const." << endl;
}

bool operator==(const student& a) const {
    if (a.name == this->name) return true;
    
    return false;
  }
};

int main()
{
   student a("Vyom");
   student c(a);
   if (a == c)
   {
       cout << "same";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau Done. Thanks for the valuable suggestion